# How to have smooth scrolling in Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: 20.04, scrolling, mouse-scroll

I miss the inertial scrolling in Windows 10. Is there a way to implement global-wide smooth scrolling in Ubuntu 20.04? The scrolling feels clunky, and I’d love for it to be smoother.